A complicated integral
I was going through a certain calculation in a paper and came across following integral to be evaluated
$$I= - \int_{\epsilon_{min}}^{\epsilon_{max}} f(\epsilon) \epsilon  \ln(\epsilon) d\epsilon \equiv \ln(\gamma N)$$
where we have
$$f(\epsilon)= \frac{N Q}{2 \pi} \frac{\sqrt{(\epsilon_{max}-\epsilon)(\epsilon-\epsilon_{min})}}{\epsilon}, \nonumber \\
    \epsilon^{max}_{min} = \frac{1}{N}\left(1+\frac{1}{Q} \pm \frac{2}{\sqrt{Q}}\right)$$
In the paper, it is asserted that the integral $I$ has the form $\ln(\gamma N)$. And further, it is written and I quote "The integral can be evaluated to a generalized hypergeometric function and the final result is"
$$\gamma = \frac{Q}{Q+1} \exp\left [\frac{Q}{2(Q+1)^{2}}\, _3F_{2} \left( 1,1,\frac{3}{2};2,3;\frac{4 Q}{(Q+1)^{2}} \right)  \right]$$.
I tried various ways to evaluate the integral but could not evaluate it. I basically tried following ways

I tried to calculate the integral $I= \int_{a} ^{b} \sqrt{(b-x)(x-a)} \ln(x) dx $. This integral is evaluated in terms of $\log$ but it is not obvious how to get back to $_3F_{2}$.
Remember the quoted statement from the paper that I mentioned above. Since the result was asserted I thought that there would be a way to bypass the complicated integral in some way and arrive at a differential equation whose solution gives the values of $\gamma$ which in turn would be easier to evaluate. But this failed as I couldn't obtain a reasonable equation to proceed.

Can anyone help me with this please? Maybe both the ways that I am thinking about are wrong and there is something else that I ought to do but I am clueless. I have already tried going through various integral tables to see something reasonable but it is of no help either.
Link to the paper : https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0203117 . Eq 8 and 9 are the relevant part. Thanks in advance.

The result is pretty silly, since $\gamma$ as you quoted, has an $\text{exp}$ inside it. By this trickery you can trivially satisfy this function form for a rather wide class of functions. It is also very specialised to that particular definite integral, and so is not very useful outside of the domain of application. Do you actually have to get this result?

Yes, I know the result seems rather weird. I would still like to know how to obtain it even if not in terms of $_3F_2$.

I'm also confused, but this seems like a problem for Maths.SE and not P.SE, even though it arose from here. Why did you not use $\lambda$ as the paper originally wrote, and instead converted to $\epsilon$?

I am sorry for that. I was making notes for myself and just copied and pasted from there with my notation. I thought to post it in Maths.SE but I had been previously ridiculed for posing such problems there. So I thought it is safer to put it here. If it doesn't belong here then I can remove it as well, no worries.

You should notice that $$,_3F_2\left(1,1,\frac{3}{2};2,3;x\right)=-\frac{8
\left(1-\sqrt{1-x}\right)}{x^2}+\frac{4}{x}-\frac{8 \left(\log
\left(\sqrt{1-x}+1\right)-\log(2)\right)}{x}$$

@ClaudeLeibovici thank you so much.. I think this helps a lot I had some result in terms of $\log$ so maybe I can massage it back to $_3F_2$.

There seem to be a few more problems, typos perhaps? The $(\epsilon_{max}-\epsilon)(\epsilon-\epsilon_{max})$ in the square-root is presumably meant as $(\epsilon_{max}-\epsilon)(\epsilon-\epsilon_{min})$. But even then it seems incorrect that $I$ would scale as $\ln(\gamma N)$ with $\gamma$ independent of $N$. That should be $\frac1N \ln(\gamma N)$ as far as I can see... (or something else has to be changed).

I am sorry for the first typo. I have corrected it.
As for the second point, I don't know what to say to it I picked it from the paper assuming it to be true. Maybe looking at the paper helps?

Use: $$\ln (\epsilon )=\underset{s\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\partial \epsilon ^s}{\partial s}$$ and then integrate.

The paper is manifestly mistaken. The result that they want cannot be correct.
First of all, note that
$$\tag1\epsilon^{\text{max}}_{\text{min}}=\frac1N\left(1+\frac1Q\pm\frac2{\sqrt Q}\right)=\frac1N\left(1\pm\frac1{\sqrt Q}\right)^2$$
Although I will not be using the rightmost form. Anyway, this suggests a change of variable:
Let $\epsilon=\frac1N\left(1+\frac1Q+\frac2{\sqrt Q}x\right)$ for $x\in[-1,+1]$ to convert the integral
$$
\begin{align}I
\tag2&=-\int_{\epsilon_{\text{min}}}^{\epsilon_{\text{max}}}\frac{NQ}{2\pi}\sqrt{(\epsilon_{\text{max}}-\epsilon)(\epsilon-\epsilon_{\text{min}})}\ln\epsilon\,\mathrm d\epsilon\\
\tag3&=-\int_{-1}^{+1}\frac{NQ}{2\pi}\sqrt{\left(\frac1N\cdot\frac2{\sqrt Q}\right)^2}\sqrt{(1-x)(x+1)}\ln\frac{1+\frac1Q+\frac2{\sqrt Q}x}N\ \left(\frac2{N\sqrt Q}\,\mathrm dx\right)\\
\tag4&=-\frac1{N\pi}\int_{-1}^{+1}\sqrt{1-x^2}\ln\frac{1+\frac1Q+\frac2{\sqrt Q}x}N\,\mathrm dx
\end  {align}
$$
Now, we can break the logarithm into two parts, extracting the $N$ part out alone. That is a constant term multiplying by the famous unit semicircle area integral and so you must get $\frac N2\ln N$; the other term is $\frac1N$ multiplied by an integral involving only $Q$ and absolutely no mention of $N$.
This directly verifies Bergervoet's comment that the result is necessarily some $\frac1N\ln(\gamma N)$ and not just $\ln(\gamma N)$
This is the good place to revisit the note at the top. If you let $x=-\cos\vartheta$ and think a bit about it, you will get that the numerator of the logarithm is related to the Laplace's multipole expansion into Legendre polynomials. Although this is merely a relation and not an identity, it still suggests that maybe this would be a good next step to pursue.

Thanks. I did the integral using the trick Mariusz mentioned. Turns out the integral can be greatly simplified and the final result can be written in much simpler terms$_3F_2$ might not be required after all. Thanks for your help.
